# change of variable in mollifier

Tags: partial-differential-equations

link : [wikipedia](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Partial_Differential_Equations/Poisson%27s_equation#Multi-dimensional_mollifiers)

Consider the following standard mollifier.

$$\eta(x) = \frac{1}{z}\begin{cases} e^{-\frac{1}{1-\|x\|^2}}& \text{ if } \|x\| < 1\\
                 0& \text{ if } \|x\|\geq 1
                 \end{cases}$$
$$\eta_\epsilon(x) = \frac{1}{\epsilon^n} \eta\left( \frac{x}{\epsilon} \right)$$

---

At this time, I have a question. How to derive the next equation ?

Let $y = x / \epsilon$, then
$$\int_{B_\epsilon(0)} \eta_\epsilon(x) dx = \int_{B_1(0)} \eta(y) dy = 1$$

---

(added)
$$\int_{B_\epsilon(0)} \eta_\epsilon(x) dx = \frac 1 {\epsilon^n} \int_{B_1(0)} \eta(y) (\epsilon \, dy)$$
How to divide $\epsilon^n$?

Comment: what do you mean by the next equation?

Comment: I have added it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $x$ and $y$ are points from $R^n$, $dx$ and $dy$ represent volume element in $R^n$, i.e, $dx=dx_1dx_2\cdots dx_n$ and since $dx=\epsilon^ndy$, the cancellation takes place.

Comment: Could you explain more in detail?

Comment: $y=\frac{x}{\epsilon}$ means $(y_1, y_2,\cdots, y_n)=(\frac{x_1}{\epsilon}, \frac{x_2}{\epsilon}, \cdots, \frac{x_n}{\epsilon})$. So $dx_1=\epsilon dy_1, \cdots, dx_n=\epsilon dy_n$.

Comment: It is very clear, thank you :)

Comment: you're welcome. Good luck.